# How to generate multiple objects?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have multiple objects like this(16)

```
function Baboo(x,y,size,speed,target,sps,life){
    MobRoot.call(this,x,y,size,speed,target,sps,life);
    this.spsCoord = [500*0,500*3,500,500];
    this.coolDown = 60;
    this.atack = 0;}
    Baboo.prototype = Object.create(MobRoot.prototype);

Baboo.prototype.throw = function()
{
    projectiles.push(new Arrow(this.x,this.y,10,10,this.angle,150,this.target));
}
Baboo.prototype.update = function(){
if(this.life>0)
{
    this.sendBack();
    this.draw();
    this.checkClick();
    this.angle = CalculateSlope(this,this.target);
    this.directionUpdate();
    this.updateBuffs();
    this.x += this.direction.x;
    this.y += this.direction.y;
}}
    /*etc aditional methods*/
```

that inherit all from this object

```
function MobRoot(x,y,size,speed,target,sps,life) 
{
    this.size = size*WindowScale;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.speed=speed;
    this.colided=false;
    this.maxlife = life;
    this.life = life;
    this.buffArray = [];
    this.sps = sps;
    this.target = target;
    this.direction = 
    {
        x:0,
        y:0
    }
    //x,y,w,h
    //ex sprite[0][0] = 0,0,500,500;
    this.spsCoord = [];
    this.isBoss = false;
}
MobRoot.prototype.directionUpdate = function()
{
this.direction.x = this.speed*Math.cos(this.angle)*-1;
this.direction.y = this.speed*Math.sin(this.angle)*-1;
}
    /*aditional methods for mobRoot*/
```

and I want to generate different mobs from an array. At the moment I'm assigning a number for each type (ex: 1-Baboo 2-Spider 3-Whatever) and storing these numbers in arrays, and when I'm generating them i use a switch for each mobIndex from the array like this

```
switch(wave[i])
{

    case 1:
        mobs.push(new Baboo(arg1,arg2,...));
        break;

    case 2: 
        mobs.push(new Spider(arg1,arg2,...));
        break;

    /*...*/

    case 999: 
    mobs.push(new Whatever(arg1,arg2,...));
    break;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of solving this kind of problem?

Comment: Every time you create a new `Baboo`, you're replacing `Baboo.prototype`, so you lose all the prototype functions that you assigned when you loaded th script.

Comment: Ok, so I need to  `Baboo.prototype = Object.create(MobRoot.prototype);` outside the constructor ? @Barmar

Comment: Yes. It should just be done once, just like all the other prototype settings.

Comment: Ok, and about the way of generating each object, is there a better way than using switch? @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the constructors into an array:

```
var constructors = [Baboo, Spider, Whatever, ...];
if (wave[i] < constructors.length) {
    mobs.push(new constructors[wave[i]](arg1, arg2, arg3, ...));
}
```